# Extreme optimization of integer binary search

Tags: algorithm, optimization, micro-optimization

I'm writing a program which will need to do a very large number of binary searches—at least 10<sup>15</sup>—in a tight loop.  These together with a small number of bitwise operations will make up over 75% of the runtime of the program, so making them fast is important.  (As implemented now it takes up over 95% of the time, but that's using a very different implementation [not a search] which I am replacing.)

The array to be searched (of course, it need not be implemented as an array) is very small.  In my current case it consists of 41 64-bit integers, though techniques for optimizing arrays of other sizes would be useful.  (I've come across similar problems before.)

I can profile the data in advance to determine what ranges are most likely and how often there is a match.  Collecting this information is not too easy but I should have it by the end of the day.

My code will be in C perhaps using inline assembly; it will be compiled with a recent version of gcc.  Responses in any language are welcome; if you prefer (e.g.) FORTRAN I can translate.

So: How can I implement this search efficiently?

**Clarification:** I'm actually using the search to test membership, not to use the location in the array.  A solution that discards that information is acceptable.

---

Final code:

```
long ispow3_tiny(ulong n)
{
    static ulong pow3table[] = {
#ifdef LONG_IS_64BIT
        12157665459056928801, 0, 4052555153018976267, 1350851717672992089, 0, 450283905890997363, 150094635296999121, 0, 50031545098999707, 0, 16677181699666569, 5559060566555523, 0, 1853020188851841, 617673396283947, 0, 205891132094649, 0, 68630377364883, 22876792454961, 0, 7625597484987, 2541865828329, 0, 847288609443, 282429536481, 0, 94143178827, 0, 31381059609, 10460353203, 0,
#endif
        3486784401, 1162261467, 0, 387420489, 0, 129140163, 43046721, 0, 14348907, 4782969, 0, 1594323, 531441, 0, 177147, 0, 59049, 19683, 0, 6561, 2187, 0, 729, 0, 243, 81, 0, 27, 9, 0, 3, 1
    };

    return n == pow3table[__builtin_clzl(n)];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Idog: How to write the function in question: performing a binary search on the given 41 values.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: I don't have any of the relevant code written.  The surrounding code (several hundred lines) is fine, and the current implementation, as I mentioned, is not a search at all.  I realized that I could replace it with a search over certain values by first normalizing it to fit into one of those values.  I wrote the normalization code but not the search code, because I wasn't sure what method would be the fastest.  Thus my question.

Comment: The wiki page for [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) gives you the algorithm as pseudo code, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @pstrjds: No.  I know how to write a basic binary search.  I'm asking about an extremely optimized one, more similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Optimal_binary_search_trees than the link you gave.

Comment: Can you post the 41 64-bit values?

Comment: @Charles my bad, I misunderstood your response to @Idog - how to write the function in question

Comment: @FogleBird: Would you laugh at me if I said it was the powers of three?

Comment: @pstrjds: I guess I wasn't clear enough, my apologies.

Comment: Wow, you should of probably mentioned the values where powers of three in the question. That's the crux of any optimization.

Comment: @ldog: Yes, probably.  I was (and still am) interested in the general question because this has come up before and will again.  Actually I think I'll return to an older task to use flolo's more general solution.

Comment: Nice question, nice answer @flolo and @FolgeBird.  But if you want this to work on 32-bit systems, shouldn't you use `__builtin_clzl` instead of `clzll`?  The latter will promote its argument to `unsigned long long`, but your `#ifdef` only checks the size of `long`.

Comment: @Nemo: Probably.  Actually I should probably use the `clzl` version for both, since I'm really only using `long`s.  (In my case they're 64-bit but the program I'm working on has provisions for 32-bit systems, usually important only for Windows systems as mingw chokes on 64-bit everything.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your values are powers of three, I think we can optimize greatly. Let's look at the numbers in binary:

```
Columns are P, I, B:
P = Power (3 ^ P)
I = Index of MSB (Most Significant Bit)
B = Binary Value

00 00 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
01 01 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
02 03 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001
03 04 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011011
04 06 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010001
05 07 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011110011
06 09 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001011011001
07 11 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010001011
08 12 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100110100001
09 14 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100110011100011
10 15 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110011010101001
11 17 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101011001111111011
12 19 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000001101111110001
13 20 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000101001111010011
14 22 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010010001111101101111001
15 23 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000110110101111001001101011
16 25 0000000000000000000000000000000000000010100100001101011101000001
17 26 0000000000000000000000000000000000000111101100101000010111000011
18 28 0000000000000000000000000000000000010111000101111001000101001001
19 30 0000000000000000000000000000000001000101010001101011001111011011
20 31 0000000000000000000000000000000011001111110101000001101110010001
21 33 0000000000000000000000000000001001101111011111000101001010110011
22 34 0000000000000000000000000000011101001110011101001111100000011001
23 36 0000000000000000000000000001010111101011010111101110100001001011
24 38 0000000000000000000000000100000111000010000111001011100011100001
25 39 0000000000000000000000001100010101000110010101100010101010100011
26 41 0000000000000000000000100100111111010011000000100111111111101001
27 42 0000000000000000000001101110111101111001000001110111111110111011
28 44 0000000000000000000101001100111001101011000101100111111100110001
29 45 0000000000000000001111100110101101000001010000110111110110010011
30 47 0000000000000000101110110100000111000011110010100111100010111001
31 49 0000000000000010001100011100010101001011010111110110101000101011
32 50 0000000000000110100101010100111111100010000111100011111010000001
33 52 0000000000010011101111111110111110100110010110101011101110000011
34 53 0000000000111011001111111100111011110011000100000011001010001001
35 55 0000000010110001101111110110110011011001001100001001011110011011
36 57 0000001000010101001111100100011010001011100100011100011011010001
37 58 0000011000111111101110101101001110100010101101010101010001110011
38 60 0001001010111111001100000111101011101000000111111111110101011001
39 61 0011100000111101100100010111000010111000010111111111100000001011
40 63 1010100010111000101101000101001000101001000111111110100000100001
```

The observation is that all values have a unique MSB.

Using the x86 bit scanning instruction, we can quickly determine the MSB.

http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_6/CH06-4.html#HEADING4-67

Use the MSB as an index into a 64-entry table. Compare the value in the table with the value being checked for equality. If they are not equal, the test fails.

Edit: j_random_hacker pointed out that the lowest 8-bits are all unique as well. You might want to implement each version and see which is fastest.

Comment: I love this solution. This is better than hashing. Using BSR instruction is crucial though, since looping (or some bit trick) will be inefficient.

Comment: That's it!  I can't believe I didn't think of that, considering that I'm using that operation all over my code.  Guess it just takes a second perspective.

Comment: @Charles: If you know that every number is of the form 3^P where P is an integer, do you know P in advance? Then forget your 64-bit numbers.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: It's the opposite: I don't know if it's of the form 3^P and that's what I'm testing.  The initialization code transforms numbers in such a way that 'good' numbers become powers of three and 'bad' numbers are never powers of three.

Comment: I just coded it up, very nice and short.  I edited it into my original post in case it would be useful to someone later.

Comment: For trying to get portability and performance-where-possible, there's fairly simple algorithms that can find that bit position in time logarithmic in the number of bits (for 64 bits, 6 steps, though each step has multiple instructions). Also, many compilers have intrinsics for them. Point of interest - this is a kind of special case of perfect hashing. Maybe worth looking up bloom filters, but probably only for much larger sets of integers.

Comment: @Steve314: Right, the `__builtin_clz` family of intrinsics does it in one step.  Yes this is perfect hashing, I left a comment on flolo's answer to that extent.

Comment: @Steve314: Bloom filters would not be useful for this problem because it needs to be exact.  Bloom filters are probibilistic and the very small error is unacceptable in this case.

Comment: @Charles - normally yes, but a precalculated bloom filter can be designed (by choosing appropriate hash functions) to have no false positives - they don't have false negatives anyway. OTOH, I didn't think this through properly - a single pre-selected perfect hash function would probably do the job better than any bloom filter - there's probably no benefit to the multiple hash functions.

Comment: Even simpler: all those values are unique on their rightmost 8 bits, so just mask off the rest and look up a 256-element table; iff the entire 64-bit value agrees with the looked-up value, it's a match.  I remember years ago that x86 instructions like `BSR` (which is presumably what `__builtin_clzl()` becomes) were actually slower than handrolled loops, dunno if that's still the case, but `AND` exists on every CPU and I'm certain that it's at least as fast as bit-scan instructions on those CPUs that have them!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Nice catch! I wondered about that but didn't look in enough detail to pick up on it. I've updated my answer to mention this as well.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - based on that, I looked at noticed that for the least significant n bits, there's a repeating pattern which covers half the possible bit-patterns before cycling (haven't confirmed for certain, but seems to work). Probably some powers-of-relatively-prime-numbers thing going on. Point is, it looks like it may only need 7 bits and a 128-entry table.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - scratch that - first repeat for 7 bits at item 32. Not sure if that's the pattern breaking, or me messing up my numbers somewhere. The LSB is always 1, though, so you can still get a 128-entry table. Bit 2 is always 0, too, but probably not worth exploiting that.

Comment: @Steve314: Good idea. I was about to say, "Right-shifting to get rid of that always-1 LSB might actually wind up being slower than just using the full 256-element table", but I realise now that our hash value would need to be left-shifted several bits anyway to get an offset into a table of 64-bit elements -- so we can get rid of the "extra" right shift by just ANDing with 0xFE instead of 0xFF, and left-shifting one less bit than we previously would have!  I.e. same number of CPU instructions, but half the table size :)

Answer (score 12):

Not the answer to your question, but a suggestion for improvement: If you have to do that many queries, its maybe worth to compute first a perfect hash function for the 41 values, and then use that for getting the index.

Comment: So find a function that puts each of the values in a different bucket, then test to see if the value is the unique one in that bucket.  Nice idea.

Comment: +1 Right. You could just pick the low-order 6 bits of the key and use it as your hash function. When you store the numbers in the table, if you have a collision, start another table & put it there. Let the value 0 or -1 be reserved, to mark an empty table entry.

Comment: So, any suggestions on _fast_ families of hash functions that I can write code to search to find one that distinguishes them all?  I'm trying a few obvious 'lowest bits xor some other bits' functions by hand-ish, but I think I need to widen my parameters somewhat.  For example, `n ^ (n >> k)` gives at best 35 buckets for the optimal `k = 5` in my case.

Comment: +1. You do want to make sure your hash function is fast, though. Searching for a value across a 41-item array is not much slower than some stock hash algorithms.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: What I love about this is that, assuming I can manage it properly, there should be only 0.5 branch misprediction penalties, vs. 0.5 lg 41 for a naive binary search.

Comment: @Charles: If "most of the time" the numbers are not clumped up, `i = (key & 63);` or `i = ((key >> 6) & 63);` should work just fine. You probably want `key` to be unsigned. Better yet, make a bigger table. You get fewer collisions.

Comment: @Mike: They are clumped, though.

Comment: It looks like FogleBird has found the perfect hash function for me.  flolo, I'll leave you with the +1 and accept the other answer if you don't mind.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Charles: I dont mind. He found really a nice function/property of the numbers.

Comment: @Mike: Now that the OP has said it's the first 41 powers of 3, you were basically exactly right -- just use the low-order 8 bits as-is and you already have a perfect hash function!  :)

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way presented by Jon Bentley is, round up the table size to 64 and initially fill it with MAXINT, then do:

```
i = 0;
if (key >= a[i+32]) i += 32;
if (key >= a[i+16]) i += 16;
if (key >= a[i+ 8]) i +=  8;
if (key >= a[i+ 4]) i +=  4;
if (key >= a[i+ 2]) i +=  2;
if (key >= a[i+ 1]) i +=  1;
if (a[i]==key){
  // got it !
}
```

A dirty but even faster way is an if-tree:

```
if (key < a[32]){ // we know i >= 0 && i < 32
    if (key < a[16]){  // we know i >= 0 && i < 16
      // etc. etc.
    } else {           // we know i >= 16 && i < 32
      // etc. etc.
    }
} else {          // we know i >= 32 && i < 64
    if (key < a[48]){  // we know i >= 32 && i < 48
      // etc. etc.
    } else {           // we know i >= 48 && i < 64
      // etc. etc.
    }
}
```

A little code generator or string of macros could generate this tree.

Comment: That's a nice generic binary search.  I've certainly written a few if-trees in my day... not sure if it can be bettered in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Of course only real profiling, on real hardware and with real data will give the correct answer, but I think that probably using a binary search based on comparison is not going to be the fastest alternative (especially because modern CPUs hate branching).

To test membership if the number of failures is going to be very high (just a wild guess, but 41 is quite a bit smaller than 2**64) then IMO hashing could be a better option, resorting to real search only if the hash test is passed to avoid false positives.

The idea is

```
 for x in interesting_values:
     hmap[hash(x)] = True

 for x in data:
     if hmap[hash(x)]:
         # do a full check here
```

the hash function could be very simple (eg bitwise xor of four 16 bit groups, computed in two steps as 32 xor 32 followed by 16 xor 16) and the hash map can be 65536 bits in this case. No more than 41 bits can be set in this 64k map, so if your data is randomly distributed then the full search will be done very rarely. Depending on cache consideration may be using one byte per hash map cell is better.

Also may be using an 8-bit hash is even better but in this cases the cache hit would potentially be 41/256 instead than 41/65536.

Comment: I intend to write a basic binary search implementation later tonight and track incoming data.  Because of the normalization and the data passed to it the hits are vastly higher than you'd expect at random, but they'll still be mostly misses as you suggest.